# What spectrum analyzer can detect Wireless AD?

Tags: wifi, signal-processing, measurement-devices, high-end

[Wireless AD now has a 60GHz frequency band](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2012/11/29/the-difference-between-wireless-n-wireless-ac/).  Because of its immense bandwidth, I'd like to measure, how much ElectroMagnetic Radiation I am exposed to when I am in its vicinity.  However, the [EMR safety superstore](http://www.lessemf.com/rf.html) does not have anything that can measure over 18GHz.  After searching around on the internet, even the [most sophisticated, computer-linked spectrum analyzer](https://www.aaronia-shop.com/products/spectrum-analyzer/real-time/highend-real-time-spectrum-analyser) only has capabilities up to 20GHz.  Ironically, their company has [an antenna](https://www.aaronia-shop.com/products/antennen-sensoren/logper-antennas/log-per-antenna-up-to-35ghz) which can amplify signal up to 35GHz, in order to help EMR measurement devices determine, where the signal is coming from.  Still nowhere close to the 60GHz though.  So few similar questions:

- Is there any spectrum analyzer that can measure frequencies higher than 20GHz?
- Is there anything that can measure at least up to 35GHz, making full use of [their antenna](https://www.aaronia-shop.com/products/antennen-sensoren/logper-antennas/log-per-antenna-up-to-35ghz)?
- Is there anything that can measure Wireless AD signal strength?  I read abstracts of articles where its levels were measured, but I don't have access to the articles themselves, to see *how* these levels were measured.

Comment: 60 Ghz radio waves [require line-of-sight and are significantly attenuated by oxygen in the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_high_frequency#Propagation). The IEEE 802.11ad bands are not going to be useful for *most* consumer WiFi applications, definitely not suitable for a household WiFi network. I think it will be unlikely that you will even be exposed to *any* radiation from WiFi AD unless you're concerned about a device you're using for yourself or in the workplace.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that 60GHz is attenuated by oxygen.  I know that ADT, which runs at 95GHz, is not, and I did not realize that 60GHz is fundamentally different.  So then it's a matter of making sure that there is some obstacle between me and the radio source in the workplace.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that SAF Tehnika J0SSAP60 is exactly what you are looking for - https://www.saftehnika.com/en/ebandspectrumcompact

It is a has a bandwidth of 56 to 67 GHz, but you would need to get a quote from the manufacturer to buy it.

[SAF Tehnika J0SSAP60](https://www.saftehnika.com/files/widget_dark/14665148283171.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Because of its immense bandwidth, I'd like to measure, how much ElectroMagnetic Radiation I am exposed to

**bandwidth has nothing to do with how much electromagnetic radiation there is!**

> Asked 3 years, 9 months ago...  Modified today Viewed 68 times

*So what ever happened to 60GHz 802.11ad WiFi?*

https://www.pocnetwork.net/technology-news/so-what-ever-happened-to-60ghz-802-11ad-wifi/

> However, soon after, everything came to a stop. Few were discussing the 802.11ad standard. Instead, everyone was casting their attention to 802.11ax (which eventually became known as WiFi 6). 802.11ax operated within the 6GHz spectrum, and although it wasn’t as fast as 60GHz, it eventually became the next standard used by most companies.  So what happened? The two technologies pitted with each other were similar to the Beta vs VHS or HD vs Bluway debates. The only difference here is that 60GHz never really stood a chance. The reason for this is broadcast distance more than anything else. Sure, 60GHz could move a LOT of data quickly across your network. However, you begin to lose connection past a short distance away. It isn’t ideal for covering a good-size home.

The transmit power level of wifi6 (802.11ax) is 30dBm, or 1 watt,
It was reported the transmit power level for 802.11ad {60ghz} was upped to 40 dBm or 10 watts.  However (as was mentioned) the 60ghz band... between 57ghz and 63 ghz, is greatly attenuated by the oxygen in the atmosphere so the x10 transmit power of what was briefly 802.11ad was no cause for concern, which is likely the reason for the x10 increase in transmit power to offset the roughly 10-16 dbm of attenuation between 57-63ghz.  You do more damage to yourself using your cellphone, given the power level of the 800mhz and 2ghz frequency range they operate in.

https://www.air802.com/fcc-rules-and-regulations.html

but if you wanted to measure signal strength, in the 60ghz V-band realm, **network analyzers** such as those sold by keysight (agilent) or rohde-schwarz can do it.